# How to colour points in a dumbbell plot based on condition?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalt

I'm trying to colour the `xend` points in my dumbbell plot based on whether the `x_diff` value is positive or negative. Essentially, if the `x_diff` value is positive, I'd like the `xend` point coloured green, and if its negative, coloured red. I've attempted to define this in my data, but I come unstuck when I try and run this through `ggplot` the way I have the code written now. Does anyone have any suggestions that may help? Example code is below.

Thank you.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalt)

data <- tibble(
  id = c(paste0("player", 1:5)),
  x1 = c(0.219, 0.169, 0.103, 0.193, 0.345),
  x2 = c(0.258, -0.030, 0.071, 0.315, 0.223),
  x_diff = x2 - x1,
  point_colour = ifelse(x_diff > 0, "#046A38", "#C60C30")
)

plot <- data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_dumbbell(aes(x = x1, xend = x2, y = id), size = 2, colour = "#E3E2E1",
                size_x = 4, size_xend = 4, colour_xend = data$x_diff) +
  theme_classic()
  
plot
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution but you can overlap `geom_point()`, and color it as you prefere:

```
 data %>%
 ggplot() +
 geom_dumbbell(aes(x = x1, xend = x2, y = id),
               size = 2, colour = "#E3E2E1",size_x = 4, size_xend = 4) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x2, y = id), color = data$point_colour, size = 4) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]